# I can upload from gallery, but uploading from camera gives error 500

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, image-processing, base64

When the input changes i have a script that breaks the image to base64 and then uploads it so i can edit it server side before displaying.

If i upload from the phone's gallery it works like a charm but for some reason if i choose to upload from camera i get a 500 error.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#upload', function() {
  var files = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(files);
  reader.onload = function() {
      var base64 = reader.result;
      base64 = base64.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
      var formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("file", base64);
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("NormalizeOrientation", "Admin")',
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formdata,
        success: function(data) {
          //stuff
        },
        error: function() {}
      });
```

if i json it i get an error for the size so i pass it as base64 string directly

i also tried passing the file as HttpPostedFileBase with the same result

Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: It depends on the camera, but the files may be in RAW format and they cannot be directly encoded to a base64 PNG. Also note that you don't need to base64 encode the files at all, just `append()` them to the `FormData` object

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hi Rory thanks for trying to help again. If that's the case how can i use the image? if i take a photo offline and the upload it from the gallery it works fine, so it must be something about the temp directly from camera